# How do I enable Paredit in Light Table?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, lighttable, paredit

I'm new to Light Table, and I'm accustomed to using paredit.  The plugin manager tells me I've got the Paredit plugin installed, but I can't figure out how to enable it.  I can see the paredit commands in the command pane by typing in "paredit", but none of them have keyboard shortcuts listed.  How do I turn it on?

I need to use Light Table on different machines - surely I don't have to manually configure the keyboard shortcuts every time I use a new machine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am afraid you have to do that for paredit. It doesn't have default keyboard shortcuts defined. There is another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22168195/i-cant-find-a-light-table-cheat-sheet?rq=1) here that shows the paredit commands and how you set them up.

If you are going to use Light Table on different machines you might consider storing your user files in Dropbox or Git to sync them between your machines.

Comment: This makes me sad, but it's very useful information to know, thanks!